# Slick slider area-hidden issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am working on a Shopify website and I have added a Slick slider to my product recommendation section, but it is not working properly. It is showing area-hidden="false" after one slide is complete. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7VQha.png)

My website URL is: https://inka-corps.myshopify.com/products/inka-arne-dining-chair

Password:aichay

```js
   jQuery('.collection-slider').slick({
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     infinite: false,
     focusOnSelect: true,
     centerPadding: '0px',
     dots: true,
     infinite: true,
     draggable: true,
     autoplay: true,
     autoplaySpeed: 1500
   });
```

Comment: Do you mean `aria-hidden`? If so, that's just to make the slide visible for assistive technology users (e.g. screen readers). See [Using the aria-hidden attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-hidden_attribute). Is that causing a problem for you?

Comment: But I am facing issue in my slick slider,

Comment: What is the actual problem you are seeing?